# How to setup api authorization if I don't have a login page in my website

Tags: reactjs, websecurity, api-authorization

I want to set up authorization in my react app. This is for security reasons, so my API will only be accessed by the people who use our website. But my web app doesn't have a user login and doesn't require any. my backend uses rest api.

- How would I proceed with authorization with a token?
- How can I set up an initial token even before the page loads?

Comment: set token in cookie when people first access your website?
But point is, whats your token strategy without login, machine ID or IP?

Answer (score 0):

Something like a token will not work since it sounds like your app is public and therefore anyone could grab the token (being a browser based thing) and use that on their own. Instead I'd explore CORS to control the origin - for example only allowing your website to be authorized to perform the api call. Here's an article on using CORS with the AWS API Gateway.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html

It's possible to spoof this however but without a login system you may be hard pressed to create something really secure. There is no way to effectively hide a token embedded in a website unless it is provided by the user which mean a login page or some  similar method to provide a token.  The question is since your API is evidently not holding private information then your concern would then be of preventing DDOS attacks at which point you should look into offsetting that with the proper tools/systems.

Comment: yes it's a public website, but is the cors enough for authorization

Comment: I've updated my answer with more info.